# I am attempting to iterate through and compare two different 2 - dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to iterate through two different 2 - dimensional arrays. I am looking to iterate through and compare each index of the paths array to each index of the patterns array.  If the arrays are the same length, I am looking for an index that matches or has a wildcard character at that index, at which point I will pass it to another function for further refinement.

I am having difficulty finding which combinations of methods to use in order to control my iterating through this whole process without getting out of sync.  There's a lot more to the problem, but refining my tactics here will definitely help me on the road to success with the rest of it.

```
Paths:
[ [ 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ],
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
[ 'foo' ],
[ 'foo', 'bar' ],
[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] ]

Patterns: 
[ [ '*', 'b', '*' ],
[ 'a', '*', '*' ],
[ '*', '*', 'c' ],
[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ],
[ 'w', 'x', '*', '*' ],
[ '*', 'x', 'y', 'z' ] ]

let determineMatch = (paths, patterns) => {

let exactMatch = null;
let potentialMatches = [];

paths.forEach( path => {
  for (let i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < patterns[i].length; j++) {
      if (path.toString() === patterns[i].toString()) {
        exactMatch = patterns[i]
        break;
      } else if (path.length === patterns[i].length && patterns[i].includes('*')) {

        if(potentialMatch(path, patterns)) {
          potentialMatches.push(patterns[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})`
```

Comment: why to use second iterator(j) when its of no use?

Comment: Fair question, I had included it before in order to access at patterns[i][j] but am currently not using that.  This may be contributing to my "out-of-sync" or redundant behavior.

Comment: It seems that each `path` is an array and inside the 2nd `for` loop an entire array is being compared to a single array element.

Comment: @radarbob He is not comparing to `patterns[i][j]` but `patterns[i]`

Comment: @radarbob so I've taken your advice with regards to iterators/iterables and nested two `for...of` blocks, one that is `for (let path of paths)` and inside of that `for (let pattern of patterns)`.  Does this take care of this issue?

Comment: @wrangler is on the right track.... and you said 'redundant behavior'. That may be due to the `for( j = 0...` loop causing `path` to `patterns[i]` comparing "patterns[i].length times".

Answer (score 0):

```
async.each(paths,(path,cb)=>{
    async.each(patterns,(pattern,callback){
         if(path.toString() == pattern.toString()){
               exactMatch = pattern;
               return cb(exactMatch);
         }else if(path.length == pattern.length && pattern.includes('*')){
               if(potentialMatch(path, pattern)) {
                      potentialMatches.push(pattern);
               }
         }
         callback();
    },()=>{})
    cb();
},()=>{
   console.log("Done");
})
```